# Event doesnt fired on the client using Node js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have problems when i upload an image to my server, when i do that i want to emit this event to the room "1room"

```
 `io.sockets.in("1room").emit('image_added','OK');`
```

the problem is, the event doesnt fired on the client, but if i reload the page yes, the event is fired.

HTML

```
 <form ref='uploadForm' 
      id='uploadForm' 
      action='http://localhost:3000/upload' 
      method='post' 
      encType="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
       <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
 </form>
```

SERVER

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

   socket.join("1room");

});

    app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

      if (!req.files)
        return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

      let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

      sampleFile.mv('/xampp2/htdocs/pic.jpg', function(err) {

        if (err)
          return res.status(500).send(err);

     if (res.status(200)){
            io.on('connection', function(socket){
            io.sockets.in("1room").emit('image_added','OK'); 
    });

        }

      });

    });
```

CLIENT

```
socket.on('image_added', function(status) {

   alert(status);

});
```

Comment: Why are you using io.on('connection' again in the post request?

Comment: Also, Don't use Stackoverflow for question that can be fixed with a couple of more searches and or a little more effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
 if (res.status(200)){
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        io.sockets.in("1room").emit('image_added','OK'); 
    });
}
```

to this:

```
 res.status(200);
 io.sockets.in("1room").emit('image_added','OK');
```

You can't put an `io.on('connection', ...)` inside an `app.post()` nor would you ever want to.  The event does not occur while that route is being processed.  Instead, you just want to broadcast to all connection clients in that room with `io.sockets.in("1room").emit('image_added','OK');`

In addition, there's no point to `if (res.status(200))` because that is always true since `res.status()` just returns the `res` object.

Answer (score 0):

simple you are only sending if there is brand new connection event fire.

```
io.sockets.in("1room").emit('image_added','OK')
```

remove the connection event.